# ErrorListPlot Not Plotting

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to use `ErrorListPlot` on *Mathematica* 6.0 (it's the copy my school gave me for a lab course).

When I run this function it produces a graph, but there is nothing on it. I've checked the input and done some basic troubleshooting:

- I have checked the table constructed using `ErrorBar` and it's good.
- I've also set the `PlotRange` to more than large enough for the data.
- And I've used Needs["ErrorListPlot``"] in a cell prior to the one I'm
  evaluating right now.
- I've also tried quitting the kernel and redoing everything.

Can someone tell me why it simply won't plot the data?
The strange thing is that no errors are reported my *Mathematica*. The data all comes out nice an clean, but the plot is just a blank canvas.

Comment: Hi ! Please, provide the code you are using so we can reproduce the problems you are having :)

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem with V10.0.2. Here is my `plotdata2`:{{30., 5.2/Sqrt["462"]}, {29.3, 3.9/Sqrt["4"]}, {27.2, 8.2/Sqrt[
  "80"]}, {23.2, 8.3/Sqrt["9"]}, {30.3, 7.3/Sqrt["15"]}, {27.9, 6.2/
  Sqrt["10"]}, {22.3, 11.2/Sqrt["6"]}, {23.4, 8/Sqrt["3"]}, {13.2, 
  13.2/Sqrt["1"]}, {21., 21./Sqrt["1"]}}  With   `ErrorListPlot[plotdata2]` I only get an empty canvas, with axes in the generic region from 0 to 1. Any idea, what's wrong?

Comment: @Lea -- You need to get rid of the quotation marks in the argument to `Sqrt` in your data. They cause the numbers to be parsed as strings; `Sqrt` doesn't know what to do with strings, so it goes unevaluated.

Comment: This question should be addressed to the course's teaching staff.